# Object from Pointer in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I'm attempting to create my first Parse Cloud Code function and am running into an issue:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Message", function(request) {

  var fromUser = request.object.get("fromUser");
  var toUser = request.object.get("toUser");

  console.log(fromUser); // user pointer
  console.log(toUser); // user pointer

});
```

As you can see both `fromUser` and `toUser` is a pointer when what I actually want is the user objects themselves. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Kyle, did you make it work?

Comment: @giorgionasis sadly no.

Comment: I am almost there to make it. I will inform you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new query to get user informations.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.get(request.object.get('fromUser').id, {
    success: function(user) {
        // What you want with user informations
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

---

You can try this, but I've never try.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.equalTo('objectId', request.object.get('fromUser').id);
query.equalTo('objectId', request.object.get('toUser').id);

query.find({
    success: function(users) {
        // What you want with users information
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

Comment: So I would need to two two of these (one for `toUser` and one for `fromUser`)?

Comment: Maybe you can get the two users information with one query. But I never try.

Comment: that's not gonna work. the last objectId will be considered. it will never get 2 users.
getting user by id will ALWAYS return 1 user only.

Answer (score 0):

I am too late, but I hope this will work

you can use

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Message", function(request, response) { ....
```

or

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Message", function(request) { ....
```

.

### this is how to use beforeSave

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Message", function(request, response) {
    var message = request.object;
    var fromUser = message.get("fromUser"); // you must have this User object, if it's null, then the object is null in the table
    var toUser = message.get("toUser");

// fromUser and toUser columns must be Pointer<User> and have values

    }).catch(function(error) {
        response.error("Error finding message " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    });

    });
```